# Swift: how to replace \U literal encoding into plain UNICODE characters?

Tags: swift, unicode, data-conversion

Say I have the following String originated from a server :

```
let uLiteralEncoded = "Derri\U00e8re le transfert d&#39;Anthony Martial"
```

I'd like to replace it by the String as follows:

```
var plainEncoded = "Derrière le transfert d'Anthony Martial"
```

Comment: You should give some examples of some things you've tried. SO isn't a coding service, everyone is here to help, but you should show us what you've attempted and then we'll help you figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With further trials, I found the solution finally.

The format is an HTML format with HTML entities (hence the quote as &#39; and the diacritics with \U coding).

then I wrote a String extension that build a standard Swift 4 String from it as a constructor as follows:

```
extension String {

    /// String as HTML
    init(htmlEncodedString: String) {
        let encodedData = htmlEncodedString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let attributedOptions : [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]
        do {
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)

            self.init(attributedString.string)
        }
        catch {
            self.init(htmlEncodedString)    // Something gone wrong, stick with the initial string
        }
    }
}
```